# Comparing huge data from two different sides

Tags: javascript, json, verification

I have 2 different data storages which have same data stored in them. I want to check if both of them are similar. The type of data is

```
const object1 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30",
  "height": "180 cm",
  "standard": "10th"
}
```

it should consider the data same even if the order of the data in the object is changed.

I have tried to generate the hash of the data and in batches and then check for their equality. But still as the input data is large it is still not a feasible way.

I want a efficient solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```js
function objectsAreEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let key of keys1) {
    if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) || obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

const object1 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30",
  "height": "180 cm",
  "standard": "10th"
};

const object2 = {
  "standard": "10th",
  "age": "30",
  "name": "John",
  "height": "180 cm"
};

console.log(objectsAreEqual(object1, object2));
```

Comment: That's correct ✅

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object1).split("").sort().join("") === JSON.stringify(object2).split("").sort().join(""));
```